# docker compose cannot detect the update after error

Tags: mongodb, express, docker-compose

I try to use the docker-compose for mongodb and express which i know that there are some error on the mongodb part which remain unfix for the connection.But the there are error on server.js after when running docker-compose up.When i update the file , docker cannot detect the update which remain unchange with the same error message.

error message:

```
 expressnew | ff
    expressnew | /usr/src/app/server.js:8
    expressnew | app.use(cors());
    expressnew |     ^
    expressnew | 
    expressnew | ReferenceError: cors is not defined
    expressnew |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server.js:8:5)
    expressnew |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    expressnew |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
    expressnew |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
    expressnew |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    expressnew |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    expressnew |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongo_ex
    image: mongo
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=Alexso0121
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=LR4135alex
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db
  app:
    container_name: expressnew
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    build: .
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mongodb
      - DB_USER=alexso0121
      - DB_PASSWORD=LR4135alex
      - DB_NAME=
      - DB_PORT=$MONGODB_DOCKER_PORT
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  db:
```

server.js (after update):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
console.log("ff")
const mongoose=require('mongoose')  
mongoose.set('strictQuery',false)
require('dotenv/config')


app.use(bodyParser.json());


const db=mongoose.connection
db.on('error',(error)=>console.error(error))
db.once('open',()=> console.log('connect to db'))

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION
    ,{ useNewUrlParser:true })
app.use(logger)

//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/',logger,(req,res)=>{
    console.log("ddd")
    //res.status(500)
    res.json({ username : "alex"})

})

const userRouter = require('./routes/users')

function logger(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.originalUrl)
    next()
}
app.use('/users',userRouter)
app.listen(3000)
```

I have use docker-compose down but nothing happen which the container are not actually generated.I am wondering how to fix this.